# Error Processing Request: "Invalid website id requested."

Tags: magento, report, admin

After I delete my other website in magento I get this error:

"There has been an error processing your request + error log number #####"

and this is the number file from var/report/

```
a:5:{i:0;s:29:"Invalid website id requested.";i:1;s:3490:"#0 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(950): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Invalid website...')
#1 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(465): Mage_Core_Model_App->getWebsite('5')
#2 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(150): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getWebsite()
#3 /var/www/html/store/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/tax/notifications.phtml(31): Mage_Tax_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->getWebsitesWithWrongDiscountSettings()
#4 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/s...')
#5 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#6 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#7 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(196): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Tax_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->_toHtml()
#10 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#12 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)
#14 /var/www/html/store/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')
#15 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/s...')
#16 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#17 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#24 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#25 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 /var/www/html/store/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 /var/www/html/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}";s:3:"url";s:76:"/store/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/f819ce7010059de6034bd3395cd50f4d/";s:11:"script_name";s:16:"/store/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

How can I resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Check in your index: `Mage::run('', 'store')`. You probably should now be passing another store code through apache/nginx (variable `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']`)

Answer (score 3):

if u got this error after deleting sotore you can try this solution :

1. select **core_website** and look for **website_id** attribute.
2. delete all lines in  **core_store** and **core_store_group** tables has
   **website_id** attribute deference to  **core_website.website_id**.

Answer (score 1):

In the catalog_product_website table, make sure that products are only associated with active websites. For example, to delete associations between all websites except website id 1, use the following SQL:

DELETE FROM catalog_product_website WHERE website_id != 1